# Center steps in CSS and Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this code:

```css
    .progressbar li{
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 22px;
    }
    
    .progressbar{
        counter-reset: step;
    }
    .progressbar li:before{
        content:counter(step);
        counter-increment: step;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #DCE1E6;
        color: #1F2226;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .progressbar > li:nth-child(2):before {
        background: #FFC700;
        color: #1F2226;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="basket">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="progressbar w-100">
                    <li>Koszyk</li>
                    <li>Dostawa</li>
                    <li>Płatność</li>
                    <li>Podsumowanie</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Preview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/

I need this effect: https://ibb.co/3zBV0vz

1. Center the steps / dots in the center of the screen
2. Add the distance between the dot / step and the text next to it

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `float` but use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead.

UPDATE: grey border added on `li` elements except for the last one.

```css
.progressbar li {
  width: 20%;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #DCE1E6;
  color: #1F2226;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.progressbar>li:nth-child(2):before {
  background: #FFC700;
  color: #1F2226;
}
```

```html
<section class="basket">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="progressbar w-100">
        <li>Koszyk</li>
        <li>Dostawa</li>
        <li>Płatność</li>
        <li>Podsumowanie</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I update my project: serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka on your's code. ibb.co/3zBV0vz - Do you know how to add vertical gray stripes?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using Bootstrap v4, you could use some handy [utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/) which Bootstrap provides.

You could use flexbox to center your box vertically and horizontally:

```html
<section class="basket">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="progressbar w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <li>Koszyk</li>
        <li>Dostawa</li>
        <li>Płatność</li>
        <li>Podsumowanie</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

- `d-flex`: Just adds `display: flex;` to your container. The following classes can only be used with a flex container.
- `justify-content-center`: Defines the alignment along the main axis
- `align-items-center`: Defines the default behavior for how flex items are laid out along the cross axis on the current line.

To add a distance between the dot and the text, alter your `margin` propery as follows:

```css
.progressbar li:before{
  /* ... */

  margin: 0 12px 10px auto;

  /* ... */
}
```

To add a separator to each step you could utilize the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo selector as you already did it with the `::before` selector:

```css
.progressbar li::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    right: 20%;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

More handy utilities from Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/

A very good writeup for flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I update my project: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/ on your's code. https://ibb.co/3zBV0vz - Do you know how to add vertical gray stripes?